# How to process a Queue in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, queue, coroutine

I've implemented a `System.Collections.Queue` in my game to gather all the incoming TCP messages.

For now, I simply process the oldest message in the `Queue` in `Update()` (if the queue is not empty)

However, the time between two frames is often way longer that the time taken to process a message.

I would like to know if there is a way to process a message just when the previous one is completed, without freezing the game.

I've tried with coroutines, but it changed nothing since `yield return null;` seems to wait for next frame (so it's like an Update()).

Comment: Without posting your TCP code it would be hard to tell what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Messages are just piece of information that can arrive at anytime. Sometimes it can be more than a hundred messages in one second, and Unity needs to process them one by one. But I can't afford waiting 1/60s between each

Comment: Use some kind of thread to process the messages in the background or use the async methods provided by the TCP class instead of queuing them.

Comment: Again, without seeing your code I can't tell what's going on. I asked for a code because I have a feeling you are doing this in the main Thread which would slow down Unity or even freeze when reading from server. Like null said, you have to do this in another Thread or use async functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement [`CustomYieldInstruction`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomYieldInstruction.html) to wait till your message arrives:

```
class WaitWhileMessageArrives: CustomYieldInstruction 
{
    Func<bool> m_Predicate;

    public override bool keepWaiting { get { return m_Predicate(); } }

    public WaitWhileMessageArrives(Func<bool> predicate) { m_Predicate = predicate; }
}
```

use it like this:

(NOTE: this code is just an example to give the basic idea, as you haven't provided your code)

```
IEnumerator ProcessMessages()
{
    while(yourQueue.Count != 0)
    {
        Message msg = yourQueue.Dequeue();
        yield return new WaitWhileMessageArrives(() => msg.processed);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps